# Php Artisan and Tinker not finding laravel project classes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laragon

I happened to open two instances of Laragon at the same time. After that php artisan migrate started throwing strange errores like "Interface not found" when that interface is actually there and was correctly imported. Tried different migrations and also throws random errors. I even tried with an old (already migrated) migration, copy pasted the code and it also didn't work. Always related to classes/interfaces not being found.

I've just noted that a simple test:

```
<?php

use App\Book;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class BookTest extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        echo Book::HARDCOVER;

    }

}
```

doesn't work; it says: 'Class 'App\Book' not found' . The book class is there and was imported from phpstorm with a simple click. So, php artisan isn't finding any of my project classes.

I've just confirmed that tinker can't find the classes either.

Ok, I've just noticed that if I change in the book class the namespace to '\App\Models\Store' (where the file actually is) and I do from tinker something like \App\Models\Store\Book::HARDCOVER, then it actually works. The thing I don't get is why it's now (suddenly) needing me to update the name space to work...

Comment: have you tried clearing cache (e.g.: `artisan cache:clear`) or regenerating autoloader (e.g.: `composer dump-autoload`)?

Comment: yes, I have a clean.bat script that does these steps: php artisan down
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan auth:clear-resets
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
php artisan up
composer dump-autoload

Comment: also, which laravel version is this? shouldn't it be `\App\Models\Book` rather than `\App\Book`? can you post the content of `app/Book.php`? maybe the namespace in that file is wrong?

Comment: it's laravel 5.8, it was working (for years) suddenly it cant find anything. Even models that are there since 2017

Comment: @Kristian please see my last edit.

Comment: its likely because you upgraded/updated to latest (or maybe just later) laravel version (e.g.: with `composer update`)

Comment: I didn't do composer update. And this started happening suddenly today a few hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how but my composer version was 2 so I had to downgrade to 1.10 and all works again.